# SpaceFillingMolecularPlot using CAS number of a compound

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

When I tried to get 3D graphics for the molecule with CAS number 52364-73-5 using *Mathematica* 10, it produced the following result:

```
ChemicalData["CAS52364-73-5", "SpaceFillingMoleculePlot"]
```

> ```
> Missing["NotAvailable"]
> ```

but it makes a plot for caffeine:

```
ChemicalData["Caffeine", "SpaceFillingMoleculePlot"]
```

How can I get a structural diagram for my compound?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on v10 win7/64 bit.  Try `RebuildPacletData[]` and then see if that changes things.

Comment: I get the OP's result on OS X for in both V9 and V10.

Comment: i also get op's result on Version 9.0.1.0 Windows 8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**added 4/26/2020**

`Molecule[]` + `MoleculePlot3D[]` can now do this directly in version 12.1:

```
MoleculePlot3D[Molecule["CAS52364-73-5"], PlotTheme -> "Spacefilling"]
```

---

## Original answer

Since the compound of interest does not have the required 3D structure within `ChemicalData[]`, we must look for other sources. One possibility is to use the [CACTUS Chemical Identifier Resolver](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure), which can take e.g. a [SMILES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) string and output a *.mol file that can the be displayed in 3D.

Generate the SMILES string:

```
smiles = ChemicalData["CAS52364-73-5", "SMILES"]
   "CCCCCCCCOC1=CC=C(C=C1)C2=CC=C(C=C2)C#N"
```

Here is a little routine that retrieves (or tries to) the corresponding *.mol file from CACTUS:

```
CactusGet[arg_String, opts___] := Import[StringTemplate[
      "https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/`spec`/file?format=sdf&get3d=true"] @
      <|"spec" -> StringReplace[If[StringMatchQ[arg, "InChI*"], arg, URLEncode[arg]],
                                "+" -> "%20"]|>, "MOL", opts]
```

Here goes:

```
CactusGet[smiles, "Rendering" -> "Spacefilling"]
```

[image: space-filling model]

---

Of course, not all known compounds are in CACTUS; one might then try to write routines for retrieving data from e.g. [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/) or [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/).

Luckily, `ServiceConnect[]` and `ServiceExecute[]` allow one to access these sources directly from within *Mathematica*.

In the case of ChemSpider, you will need to [register](http://www.chemspider.com/Register.aspx) to obtain a security token, which *Mathematica* will prompt you for when you first use the service.

After doing that, you can then use this:

```
GetChemSpider[str_String, opts___] := Module[{res}, 
   res = ServiceExecute["ChemSpider", "Search", "Query" -> str] @ "ID"; 
   If[! FailureQ[res], 
      Import["http://www.chemspider.com/FilesHandler.ashx?type=str&3d=yes&id=" <> res,
             "MOL", opts], $Failed]]
```

I'll use some examples that are a bit more interesting than the one in the OP:

```
GetChemSpider[#, "Rendering" -> "Spacefilling"] & /@
{"4493-23-6", "4368-28-9", "1256580-46-7"} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: some molecules]

For PubChem, you can query with CAS numbers like so:

```
ServiceExecute["PubChem", "CompoundSDF", {"Name" -> "138261-41-3"}]["Graphics3D", 1]
```

[image: imidacloprid]

but as you can see, the result returned is "fake 3D"; this is probably a problem on PubChem's end, tho.

---

Still another possibility presents itself if you happen to have [OpenBabel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page) also installed on your computer. Here's how to use OpenBabel's conversion capabilities from within *Mathematica*:

```
OpenBabelStructure[arg_String, opts___] := 
    ImportString[RunProcess[{"obabel", If[StringMatchQ[arg, "InChI*"], "-iinchi", ""], 
                             "-:" <> "\"" <> arg <> "\"", "-omol",
                             "--gen3d", "-c", "--minimize"}] @
                 "StandardOutput", "MOL", opts]
```

(See [this](https://openbabel.org/docs/dev/Command-line_tools/babel.html) for information on the command line options used.)

Using the same example as the CACTUS one:

```
smiles = ChemicalData["CAS52364-73-5", "SMILES"];
OpenBabelStructure[smiles, "Rendering" -> "Spacefilling"]
```

[image: space-filling model]

Answer (score 5):

The information you ask for is simply not in Wolfram's curated database. The following works

```
ChemicalData["CAS52364-73-5", "CHBlackStructureDiagram"]
```

[image: CAS52364-73-5]

showing that queries on molecule CAS52364-73-5 are possible. My conclusion is that the 3D structure data needed to satisfy your query is not in the database.

I verified my conclusion by doing an Wolfram|Alpha query from *Mathematica*.

[image: query]

Comment: How can I get SpaceFillingMoleculePlot with custom .xyz file? I tried Import["custom.xyz","Rendering"->"Spacefilling"] which gives nice 3D plot with shining. How can I eliminate shining?

Comment: @user12609. I'm sorry but I don't have an answer to what you ask in the above comment. I recommend you post it as new question. More people will see it that way and you will have a better chance to get an answer.